# Variables redefine to garbage values even after definition

Tags: c++, recursion

After certain inputs, the variable `pscore` gets redefined to a garbage value. (I know global variables are bad practice but there is a limited scope.) This is seemingly at random but only occurring in certain cases that set `tscore = 0`.

Results should follow the logic defined and not garbage values.

I've gone through with a debugger and tried to see when the value gets changed to garbage, but no luck. I've had some people look over it already and they don't see anything looking off.

```cpp
    int pscore = 0;
    int tscore = 0;
    int cscore = 0;
    bool again = false;

    int rollDie(){
        return random() % 6 + 1;
    }

    int pTurn(){
        if (again == true){
             print("Do you want to roll again (Y/N)?:"); 
        } else {
             print("Do you want to roll a dice (Y/N)?:"); //asks player if 
    they want to pass the turn   
        }
         again = true;
         string no;
         getline(cin, no); //reads from console and sets it to a string 
    called 'yes'
         if (no.compare("n") == 0){ //checks if the player inputs yes or 
     variants
             return tscore; //ends the turn
        } else {
             int i = rollDie(); //rtd
             switch(i){
                 case 1:
                     print("You rolled a 1");
                     tscore++;
                     print("Your turn total is ", tscore);
                     pTurn();
                     break;
                case 2:
                    print("You rolled a 2");
                    print("Your turn total is 0");
                    tscore = 0;
                    return tscore;
                    break;
                 case 3:
                    print("You rolled a 3");
                    tscore = tscore + 3;
                    print("Your turn total is ", tscore);
                    pTurn();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    print("You rolled a 4");
                    print("Your turn total is 15");
                    tscore = 15;
                    return 15;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    print("You rolled a 5");
                    print("Your turn total is 0");
                    tscore = 0;
                    return tscore;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    print("You rolled a 6");
                    tscore = tscore + 6;
                    print("Your turn total is ", tscore);
                    pTurn();
                    break;
                default:
                    return tscore;
                    break;

             }
        }
    }

void ggame(){
    if (pscore <= 80){
        print("It is now human's turn");
        again = false;
        print("");
        pscore = (pscore + pTurn()); //adds player score to the total score calculated that turn
        print("computer: ", cscore);
        cout << "human: " << pscore << endl;
        //print("human: ", pscore);
        print("");
        tscore = 0; //resets turn score
        if (pscore >= 80){cout << "human: " << pscore << endl;
            print("Congratulations! human won this round of Jeopardy Dice!");
            return; //breaks out of the recursion loop
        }
    }
    if (cscore <= 80){
        print("It is now computer's turn");
        print("");
        cscore = (cscore + cTurn()); //adds computer score to the total score calculated that turn
        print("computer: ", cscore);
        cout << "human: " << pscore << endl;
        //print("human: ", pscore);
        print("");
        tscore = 0; //resets turn score
        if (cscore >= 80){
            print("Congratulations! computer won this round of Jeopardy Dice!");
            return; //breaks out of the recursion loop
        } 
    }
   ggame(); //recursion
}
```

Comment: You've been told before about [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: With the exception of a few compiler bugs I've tripped over, I've found that this statement to be true: *Results should follow the logic defined and not garbage values.* The trick is not providing garbage logic.

Comment: `int pTurn()` and `int cTurn()` you have `"warning: control reaches end of non-void function"` which is fairly self-explanatory.

Comment: btw, you don't need `break` after a `return`, it will never reach the `break`

Comment: @kmdreko While `break;` after `return` isn't reached, it's generally acceptable form to include it with each case statement. You are just as likely to draw a comment about failing to include it if it isn't present. The thought process being that if the return is changed later to something else, you don't inadvertently invoke fall-though behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following case,

```
        case 1: //adds 1 to the score and allows the player to keep playing on the same turn
            print("Computer rolled a 1");
            tscore++;
            print("Computer turn total is ", tscore);
            cTurn();
            break;
```

and a few more like it, discard the result of the recursive call to `cTurn` and return nothing.

So

```
cscore = (cscore + cTurn());
```

performs arithmetic on whatever the program sees fit. In other words, garbage in, garbage out.

Solution:

```
return cTurn();
```

not

```
cturn();
```

Many modern compilers will emit a compiler warning over this. A compiler warning means that while the code is syntactically correct and produces a program, the program likely does not do what you want. Do not ignore compiler warnings. They are the first line of defense against logic errors.

If your compiler did not warn you, get a better compiler or consult the compiler documentation on how to turn up the verbosity of the warning messages.

Answer (score 0):

You have cases in `pturn()` where you exit without returning a value.  This will add whatever garbage on the stack to `pscore`.